# objectiveflickr Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, clang, objectiveflickr

Using ObjectiveFlickr, Xcode 4.5.2, iOS 6.

When compiling, it gets me:

```
Ld /Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shutterbug.    app/Shutterbug normal i386
    cd /Users/axu/prj/ios/Shutterbug
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.    app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.    app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -    L/Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -    F/Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist     /Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Intermediates/Shutterbug.build/Debug-    iphonesimulator/Shutterbug.build/Objects-normal/i386/Shutterbug.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -    Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 /Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-    ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectiveFlickr/ObjectiveFlickr     /Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libObjectiveFlickr.a -    framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-    ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shutterbug.app/Shutterbug

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Products/Debug-    iphonesimulator/ObjectiveFlickr/ObjectiveFlickr'
```

I don't know why it is asking a **/ObjectiveFlickr/ObjectiveFlickr which I never set anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you review the command starting with:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/...
```

you will find:

```
/Users/axu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Shutterbug-ecsrjcjimihxevguffdchwqnqtzf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectiveFlickr/ObjectiveFlickr
```

So there is definitely something wrong in your project.

One easy way to check this is opening your `*.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` project file in a text editor and search for `ObjectiveFlickr` to see if everything is correct.

Comment: I opened that (not a xml btw), and I can find several places has ObjectiveFlickr but can not find /ObjectiveFlickr/ObjectiveFlickr anywhere...